# PID in arch-chroot is incorrect

Tags: arch-linux, process, chroot, namespace

I am trying to run a python script in a `chroot` (specifically, the `chroot` is created with `arch-chroot`). The python script relies on `os.getpid()`, but this seems to be returning an incorrect PID within the `chroot`. If in python I do

```
import os
os.getpid()
```

I get a PID that is not listed in `/proc/` in either the chroot or real root. Further, what I think is the correct PID is listed in `/proc/` in both the chroot or real root.

The issue is not Python specific. If I run the following Bash script in the `chroot`

```
echo $$
ps -a
ls /proc
```

The PID is not listed by `ps` or in `/proc`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to get the correct PID?

Comment: I just added the python tag but that got me wondering whether it's python specific or not. Does running a bash script with `echo $$` work as expected?

Comment: @terdon It does not work as expected in bash. Thanks for the hint. I added a bash example and removed the python tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`arch-chroot`](https://projects.archlinux.org/arch-install-scripts.git/tree/arch-chroot.in) does more than create a chroot: it also [creates a PID namespace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html).

> unshare --fork --pid chroot "$chrootdir" "$@"

As the name suggests, a PID namespace has its own set of process IDs, distinct from the rest of the system. This means that processes inside the namespace can't see the processes outside the namespace (and in particular can't kill or trace them), and processes outside the namespace¹ see them with different PIDs.

For more information on namespaces, read [my summary here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92177/kernel-namespaces-support) and [the LWN series by Michael Kerrisk](https://lwn.net/Articles/531114/#series_index), especially [Part 3: PID namespaces](https://lwn.net/Articles/532271/) and [Part 4: more on PID namespaces](https://lwn.net/Articles/532748/), as well as [the earlier article by Pavel Emelyanov and Kir Kolyshkin](http://lwn.net/Articles/259217/). [how to find out namespace of a particular process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113530/how-to-find-out-namespace-of-a-particular-process) and [Reliable way to jail child processes using `nsenter:`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124162/reliable-way-to-jail-child-processes-using-nsenter) may also be of interest.

If you want to do things to a process running in a namespace from outside, you can use the [`nsenter` utility](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html); see [Is there a command to switch to into an existing namespace?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107123/is-there-a-command-to-switch-to-into-an-existing-namespace). You can also use the [`nsenter` Python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nsenter). Or you can arrange to do these operations from inside the namespace (this may or may not be a good solution depending on your architecture and security requirements); it's easier to access something in a chroot from the outside (just prefix the right directory path) than in a PID namespace.

Note that PID namespaces and chroots are independent. If you chroot to the same directory independently, that doesn't let you reach the same PID namespace. If you run `arch-chroot` twice on the same directory, you end up working in the same directory, but in two different PID namespaces.

¹  <sub>More precisely, in an ancestor namespace. (Namespaces have a tree structure where children are confined within the parent.)</sub>